# Unable to use data from Google Cloud Storage in App Engine using Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-app-engine-python

How can I read the data stored in my Cloud Storage bucket of my project and use it in my Python code that I am writing in App Engine?

I tried using:

```
storage_client = storage.Client()

bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
```

But I am unable to figure out how to extract actual data from the code to get it in a usable form.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by extracting data? What data do you actually want to extact? Can you give an example?

Comment: Read the blob (object). One method is to read the blob into a Python string: `contents = blob.download_as_string()`

Answer (score 0):

Getting a file from a Google Cloud Storage bucket means that you are just getting an object. This concept abstract the file itself from your code. You will either need to store locally the file to perform any operation on it or depending on the extension of your file put that object inside of a file readstreamer or the method that you need to read the file.

Here you can see a code example on how to read a file from app engine:

```
def read_file(self, filename):
  self.response.write('Reading the full file contents:\n')

  gcs_file = gcs.open(filename)
  contents = gcs_file.read()
  gcs_file.close()
  self.response.write(contents)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.

1. content = blob.download_as_string() --> Converts the content of your Cloud Storage object to String.
2. blob.download_to_file(file_obj) --> Updates an existing file_obj to include the Cloud Storage object content.
3. blob.download_to_filename(filename) --> Saves the object in a file. On App Engine Standard environment, you can store files in /tmp/ directory.

Refer [this link](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/0.32.0/storage/blobs.html) for more information.